# one mapping folder for all hibernate hbm.xml files

Tags: java, hibernate

if have all my hbm.xml files in one folder

and i try to make my hibernate.cfg.xml

to find then in this folder (with no adding one by one hbm.xml resource) 
so i add:

```
<mapping resource="*.hbm.xml"/>
```

but he trow:

```
failed.org.hibernate.MappingNotFoundException: resource: *.hbm.xml not found
```

but if i put

```
<mapping resource="testobj.hbm.xml"/>
```

it work just fine..

way?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you use JPA with hibernate as the implementation , you can configure the property `hibernate.archive.autodetection` to `hbm` to enable auto discovery of the `hbm.xml` files.

Check [this](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.5/reference/en/html/configuration.html#setup-configuration-bootstrapping).